# Do I have to change the article name when it is the extended version of my published paper?

Tags: publications, journals, computer-science, extended-paper

I'm submitting the extended version of my published conference paper to a journal that has a special issue specifically related to that conference.
Besides adding 30% of more material to the article (as the computer science routine), do I have to change the article name?

On one hand, everything is the same besides having more experiments and more formulations or extra explanations, and it is obvious that the article and the paper are the same works.
on the other hand, how people may decide to cite which one later on?

Comment: CS Prof. Jeff Offutt has an editorial on extending a conference paper to a journal paper (https://cs.gmu.edu/~offutt/stvr/26-7-October2016.html). To summarize, having the same title could be confusing for readers.

Comment: @kjacks21 I don't find that argument convincing.

Comment: To be extra clear, you could even name it "Paper Title (extended version)".

Comment: Most computer science researchers doesn't find his argument convincing.  Keeping the same title is significantly more common than changing the title.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there is no formal requirement that the title has to be changed. In fact, if the journal paper is just the long version of the conference paper, I would recommend **not** to change it, so that the connection between the two papers is obvious to people who see the paper in a list of references.

As soon as the journal version of the paper has appeared, it is generally assumed that this is the version that should be read and cited, rather than the shorter conference version. By keeping the title unchanged, you tell readers that there is no need to read the earlier one as well.

Comment: OP should check with the editor; some journals do not like this, even if they explicitly say that the journal paper can be an extended version of the conference one.

Comment: Then wouldn't that look odd having the same title being repeated in my list of publications (e.g. for CV or profile)?

Comment: @Bob No, since they are distinguished by where they appeared. On the contrary, having two papers with completely different titles that, on further inspection, turn out to be the long and the short version of the same paper might appear like cheating to some readers.

Comment: BTW, if you want to avoid such problems, you might name the confererence paper "A new result on whatever (extended abstract)" and drop the "extended abstract" in the journal version.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem with keeping the same name. Often there are multiple versions of a piece of work: early drafts, working papers, submission drafts, conference versions, publications etc. A change of name is necessary if an additional element is explored in the paper. The suggestion to double-check with the editor is good, but I believe they will not object.

I would also advise to put a visible note everywhere on the Internet that there is a published version of that paper, available at XXXXXX. That way, the readers will not stick or cite the conference version.